# How to create a matrix of indices in r?

Tags: r

I need to plot a square of [-10,10] x [-10,10], which means I need 21 x 21 = 441 points

Specifically I need a matrix where:

```
X[1,] = x points = -10, -10, ..., -10, -9, -9, ..., -9, ..., 10
X[2, ] = y points = -10, -9, ...,  10, -10, -9, ..., 10, ..., 10
X[3, ] = all zeros
```

How can I generate this matrix without doing a for loop like so (excuse the pseduocode):

```
arr = c()
for(x1 in -10:10) {
    for(x2 in -10:10) {
       arr.append(x1)
       arr.append(x2)
       arr.append(0)
    }
}
M <- matrix(arr, nrow=3, ncol=441)
```

If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `rbind(t(expand.grid(x = -10:10, y = -10:10)), 0)` similar to what @bouncyball suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the [`expand.grid`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/expand.grid.html) function to do most of the heavy lifting:

```
t(cbind(expand.grid('x1' = -10:10, 'x2' = -10:10), 'zero' = 0))
```

Here are the first five columns:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
x1    -10   -9   -8   -7   -6
x2    -10  -10  -10  -10  -10
zero    0    0    0    0    0
```

A simpler version, as suggested by @Frank:

```
t(expand.grid('x1' = -10:10, 'x2' = -10:10, 'zero' = 0))
```

And, in case you're working withthe [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org/):

```
library(tidyr)
data.frame(x1 = -10:10, x2 = -10:10, zero = 0) %>%
    expand(x1, x2, zero) %>%
    t()
```

Comment: The `tidyr` version has the first two rows `x1` and `x2` switched compared to the `expand.grid` version. From the question, it seems like the `tidyr` version is correct.